# Why can't I analyze (FxCopAnalyzers) an ASP.NET webforms project?

Tags: c#, webforms, visual-studio-2017

Why can't I analyze (FxCopAnalyzers) an ASP.NET webforms project? I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.5.5 and FxStyleCopAnalyzers 2.6.0.0. Also, I can't set a default ruleset there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Web site? Web application? Your project type matters a lot here.

Comment: I created the Web Forms project from the template in Visual Studio 2017 15.5.5.